# Python + Falcon + OpenTelemetry: Not sending traces to OTEL Collector

Tags: python, open-telemetry, falcon

I am trying to instrument my Falcon app to send traces to OTEL Collector. I am doing auto-instrument via launch command and then trying to send traces like the following:

> OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.name=terminus
> OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT='http://otel-collector:4317'
> OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT='http://otel-collector:4317'
> OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=grpc OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_INSECURE=true
> opentelemetry-instrument gunicorn -c conf.py

And then added these libraries in my app:

```
opentelemetry-distro = "0.43b0"
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp = "1.22.0"
opentelemetry-instrumentation-falcon = "0.43b0"
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> Transient error StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED encountered while exporting traces to otel-collector:4317, retrying in 1s.

I am running all this in docker-compose and my config for OTEL Collector looks like:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318

exporters:
  otlp:
    endpoint: jaeger-all-in-one:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true

processors:
  batch:

extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: :1888
  zpages:
    endpoint: :55679

service:
  extensions: [pprof, zpages, health_check]
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [otlp]
```

Comment: Could you remove `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT='http://otel-collector:4317'` and try again?
This endpoint should contain `/v1/traces`, which is automatically added when using `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT`.

Comment: Yes removed and tried but still ending up with the same error.

Comment: could you add your docker compose file?